# fold method not working while applying after toList() method in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting an error when I apply fold() method after toList()

I have a list of Map that contains data regarding income and expense and here I want to generate a report that contains monthly basis data like monthly total_expenses and total_income,

**I have solved with my way but looking for good coding and want to know how to use fold with toList in a single line statement**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> datalist = [
  {'date': DateTime(2022, 10, 7), 'isExpense': true, 'amount': 343.00},
  {'date': DateTime(2022, 10, 12), 'isExpense': false, 'amount': 424.00},
  ....
];

List<Map<String, dynamic>> reportlist = [];

getReport() {
  final months = datalist.map((e) => e['date'].month).toSet();

  int m = 0;
  double expense_sum = 0;
  double income_sum = 0;
  double netbalance = 0;

  for (var m in months) {
    
   /*
   this following statement does not work and showing error at
    previousValue+element['amount'];
    
    final answer = datalist
        .where((element) =>
    element['date'].month == m && element['isExpense'] == true)
        .toList().fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element['amount']);
        
        
        and thats why i hve to divide code in two part,
        first fetching expense records and than applying fold to that list;
        

    */
    final expenselist = datalist
        .where((element) =>
            element['date'].month == m && element['isExpense'] == true)
        .toList();

    expense_sum = expenselist.fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element['amount']);



    final incomelist = datalist
        .where((element) =>
            element['date'].month == m && element['isExpense'] == false)
        .toList();
    income_sum = incomelist.fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element['amount']);

    reportlist.add({
      'Month': m,
      'totalExpense': expense_sum,
      'totalIncome': income_sum,
      'netBalance': income_sum - expense_sum,
    });
  }
}



my output will be like {
      'month': 11,
      'totalExpense': 1200,
      'totalIncome': 2000,
      'netBalance': 800,
}
```

Comment: what error did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a variable like `final answer` that means its value gonna choose its type. but when you use `fold` without define its type you get that error. You need to define `fold` type which is `double`, like this:

```
final answer = datalist
          .where((element) =>
              element['date'].month == m && element['isExpense'] == true)
          .toList()
          .fold<double>(
              0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element['amount']);
```